# Set dynamically hour - DS1307

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, rtc

I want keep my RTC1307 always updated with my server, so I created this code to first search the time on the server then passes to getServerTime() function to divide it and set in the RTC. I use the rtc.adjust() to adjust my watch.

**Problem**: My watch is getting wrong, this is set **2165/165/165 165:165:85**. I think the problem is in defining the time in rtc.adjust(), I'm going as follows:

```
//tempDate -> May 19 2015
//tempHour -> 09:25:14
rtc.adjust(DateTime(tempDate, tempHour));
```

Does anyone know the cause of this error?

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
RTC_DS1307 rtc;

byte server[] = { 192, 168, 0, 8 };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 0, 237 };
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xAD, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

void setup() {
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    getServerTime(getSiteData());
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    delay(5000);

}

char * getSiteData()
{
    EthernetClient http;
    unsigned char startRead = 0, i = 0;
    char inString[50];

    if (http.connect(server, 80)) {
        http.println("GET /util/date.php HTTP/1.1");
        http.println("Host: ");
        http.println("Connection: close");
        http.println();

        while (http.connected()) {
            while (http.available()) {
                char c = http.read();

                if (c == '<' )
                    startRead = 1;

                else if (startRead) {

                    if (c != '>') {
                        inString[i] = c;
                        i++;
                        inString[i] = '\0';
                    } else {
                        startRead = 0;
                        http.stop();
                        http.flush();
                        return inString;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Serial.println(inString);
        http.stop();
        http.flush();
    }
    else
        Serial.println("Tentativa de conexão falhou. Sem internet ou servidor inacessivel");
}

//May 19 2015-09:17:24
void getServerTime(char* siteData)
{
    char *tempDate, //May 19 2015
        *tempHour; //09:17:24

    tempDate = strtok(siteData, "-");
    tempHour =  strtok(NULL, "-");

    rtc.adjust(DateTime(tempDate, tempHour));


}
```

Comment: As long as the string you are getting is exactly what you think it is, then that should be working.  I suspect that tempDate and tempHour don't contain exactly the right data.  Print it to serial surrounded by some markers (maybe "[" and "]") to ensure that it is exactly what you expect it to be.

Comment: Do you get the difference between  binary-coded decimal (BCD) and regular decimal values?

Comment: The numbers reported are typical of the time coming out as -1 or something like that.

Comment: I performed a debug and the string no contains  LF+CR, LFCR, CR+LF or CRLF

Comment: How about rogue spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers you are reporting are very familiar to me.  They are telling me that it is not possible to obtain the time from the RTC chip.

You are getting the time from your server, and as long as the string is actually what you think it is, then the values should be fine.  This snippet works perfecty:

```
#include <RTClib.h>

char siteData[] = "May 19 2015-09:17:24";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    char *tempDate = strtok(siteData, "-");
    char *tempHour =  strtok(NULL, "-");
    DateTime now(tempDate, tempHour);

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();   
}

void loop() {
}
```

So it must be in the passing of the data through the RTC chip that is failing.

Check that the chip is actually wired up properly, is running, and is responding normally before you try adding in the code to set the time from the server.

Comment: I forgot -> Wire.begin();   RTC.begin();

Comment: That'll do it ;)